# Bug in jQuery script on Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I use the script below to change the height of a certain div, based on the window/viewport height:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.my_container') .css({'min-height': (($(window).height()) - 630)+'px'});

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.my_container') .css({'min-height': (($(window).height()) - 630)+'px'});

 });
});
</script>
```

Works great on Ios handheld devices, but on android devices I have a bug. In portrait mode all ok. When I move the device into landscape, (window).height remains with the same value as in portrait mode. If I refresh the page, (window).height gets the correct value for landscape mode.

Tried everything, no luck... Help please?

EDIT: The weirdest part is that if I move - 630 in the script like this:

```
$('.my_container') .css({'min-height': (($(window).height(-630)))+'px'});
```

Now it works great on android, not at all on ios!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try listening for the onorientationchange and add a timeout to make sure the the properties have been adjusted.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('.my_container').css({'min-height': (($(window).height()) - 630)+'px'});
     }).trigger("resize");
    $(window).on("orientationchange", function (event) {
        window.setTimeout( function(){ $(window).trigger("resize"); }, 250);
    });    
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but still no luck: the weird part is that I modify this part $('.container-continut2').css({'min-height': (($(window).height(- 630)) )+'px'}); the script works great on android and not at all on ios....

Comment: Um, that makes no sense `$(window).height(- 630)`, says you are setting the height  to -630 pixels. and you would be setting the min height to "[Object object]px"

Comment: Does the `orientationchange` or 'resize' get called?

Comment: Yes, they do get called... Thank you for your help, will look further into this...